# NullPointerException getting a listview's adapter in a separate Asynctask class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

After some research and code attempts, I'm still getting a NullPointerException from attempting to get an ArrayAdapter from one of my fragment's listview. I have a sliding tab layout, and I'm trying to pass in Tab2's listview into my AsyncTask (AsyncTask is its own file).

Log here:

```
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at com.example.android.justdoit.IncProgressTask.onPostExecute(IncProgressTask.java:408)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at com.example.android.justdoit.IncProgressTask.onPostExecute(IncProgressTask.java:31)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
08-27 16:17:28.752    2980-2980/com.example.android.justdoit W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

In this snippet, I have Tab1 calling the AsyncTask and passing in Tab2's layout.

```
//My tab2view is declared as follows in my fragment's onCreateView
//tab2view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case(R.id.quick_pushup_button):
                new IncProgressTask(getActivity(), tab2view).execute(1, 12);
                break;
            case(R.id.quick_squat_button):
                new IncProgressTask(getActivity(), tab2view).execute(2, 12);
                break;
            case(R.id.quick_plank_button):
                new IncProgressTask(getActivity(), tab2view).execute(3, 12);
                break;
            case(R.id.quick_situp_button):
                new IncProgressTask(getActivity(), tab2view).execute(4, 12);
                break;
        }
    }
```

And in my AsyncTask's onPostExecute, this is my attempt to use the tab2view to get the Tab2 listview, its adapter, and to call notifyDataSetChanged:

```
public IncProgressTask(Context context, View rootView){
    this.context = context;
    this.rootView = rootView;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.questList);
    try {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter)list.getAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I do have an adapter set in Tab2.  It's in the onStart() method.

Snippet below:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Quest>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, questLog);
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.questList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i think its because the adapter did not set to listview before instantiating IncProgressTask so the listview in the rootview doesn't has an adapter.

Comment: i think it's much better to call AsyncTask after you initialize tab2View ..

Comment: tab2View is initialized before calling the AsyncTask.  It was initialized in onCreateView. Then the AsyncTask is called after I make an onClick event, so the task is definitely called afterwards

Answer (score 0):

in onStart() method you are initializing your listView like this right-

```
ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.questList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

remeber you are making it a local varibale. You cant use it else where and you are attaching your arrayAdapter inside this method.

I will suggest you to do something like this.

Make listView a global varibale so once initialized you can use it anywhere. kiek this-

Declare ListView on top of the class not between any methods.

```
ListView listView;
```

Then inside onStart() method initialize it.

```
listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView)//whatever;
listview.setAdpater(aa);
```

once this is done. You can use this listview anywhere. No need to initialize it again.

I hope this would help you.